# Ao tentar inserir algo no banco com mysqli da erro de boolen

Tags: php, mysqli

Mostra esse erro:

```
Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in /opt/lampp/htdocs/sala/class/Config.class.php:35
```

No meu arquivo esta assim:

```
public function Cadastrar(string $nick,string $senha,string $status, int $online_status) {
            $this->Query = $this->Conexao->prepare("INSERT INTO usuarios (nick,senha,sexo,status,online_status) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
            $this->Query->bind_param("sssi",$nick,$senha,$status,$online_status);
            $this->Query->execute();
            return "Registrado com sucesso!";
        }
```

Comment: Um dos problemas é que existem 5 colunas `(nick [1] ,senha [2] ,sexo [3] ,status [4],online_status[5])`, porém existe apenas 4 valores `(? [1],? [2] ,? [3] ,? [4])`. Esse é um dos erros, talvez haja outros.

Comment: eu tirei o sexo e continua dando erro, agora o número de colunas esta tudo certo, eu consigo inserir de boa se eu for fazer isso no mesmo arquivo da classe, mas quando uso require ou include para instanciar a classe, ai da esse erro

Comment: Ops, você esta certo, agora que percebi que tirei a variavel sexo que eu tinha mas acabei deixando o sexo na coluna mesmo, vlw cara